# Mapping CHILD collection to a separate DTO (asp net core API automapper projection)

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

my first StackOverflow question so please bear with me, and thank you for your help in advance! :)

How on earth can I get my asp.net core controller to respond with the DTO of the child collection within the DTO of the parent response? I need two separate DTOs because of some business logic constraints that call for this many-to-many relationship situation.

Tried automapper and spent the last two days of my life researching this to no avail.

I tried the following in my **Controller** but always get an empty child collection. I can get the child collection to display if I return the entity class which is not great with many to many relationships.

I want to end up with JSON that looks like...

```
[
{   prop : .., 
    prop: .., 
    collection[
              {
              prop:..,
              prop:..
              }
              ]
}
]
```

This is what I have in my controller:

```
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<LogEntryDto>> GetAllEntries()
    {
        var entryList = _context.Entries.ToList();

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<RiskGetDto>>(entryList));
    }
```

My Automapper profile classes contains simple mapping between the entities and DTOs

```
            CreateMap<LogEntry, LogEntryDto>();
            CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>();
```

I have a the following class

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}
```

And another

```
    public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries{ get; set; } = new List<LogEntry>();
}
```

And the following DTOs for each class

```
    public class LogEntryDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}
```

and...

```
    public class TagDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If I try to return a single resource and map all properties such as `var entry = _context.Entries.Where(....).Select(mapping here including child collection.ToList()).FirstOrDefault();` I get exactly the data shape I want. Maybe I just need a cleverer way to construct my list of resources before I send back to the Controller where I return the mapping. Any ideas on how to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just in case someone will be helped by this fix. My silly mistake was driven by my lack of lambda expression mileage(!!);

I needed to retrieve the full set of properties in the **GetAllEntries()** method in the service class like so (notice the **ToList()** on the **Tags** collection):

```
public List<Risk> GetAllEntries() 
        {
            var entryList = _context.Entries.Select(e=> new Risk 
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                RiskName = e.RiskName,
                RiskDescription = e.RiskDescription,
   ---->>>    **Tags = e.Tags.ToList()**
            }).ToList();

            return entryList;
        }
```

This is then passed to the controller and mapped like so:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<List<LogEntryDto>> GetAllEntries()
        {
            var entries = _entryService.GetAllEntries();

            return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<LogEntryDto>>(entries));
        }
```

And then let AutoMapper do its magic with the simple mapping profile...:

```
public EntriesProfile()
        {

            CreateMap<LogEntry, LogEntryDto>()
                .ForMember
                (dto => dto.EntryId,
                dbEntity => dbEntity.MapFrom(src => ....)
                .ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>()
                .ForMember
                (dto => dto.Name,
                 dbEntity => dbEntity.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
                .ForMember
                (dto => dto.Value,
                 dbEntity => dbEntity.MapFrom(src => src.Value))
                .ReverseMap();
        }
```